# Not able to pass complete datetime(Y-m-d H:i:s) in DB::raw in eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

```
$shop=DB::table('shops')
                    ->leftJoin('orderbookings',function($join)
                {
                    $join->on('shops.id','=','orderbookings.shop_id');
                    $join->on('orderbookings.created_at','>=',DB::raw(date("Y-m-d",strtotime("now"))));
                })
                    ->select('shops.*')
                    ->selectRaw('COUNT(orderbookings.id) as totalorder, SUM(orderbookings.grand_total) as gtotal')
                    ->orderBy('shops.shop_name', 'asc')
                    ->groupby('shops.id')
                    ->paginate(10);
```

Above code working fine(But not giving total order and amount correct) and also gives result almost close to what I want,
But I am not able to give date format (Y-m-d H:i:s), it shows syntax error. I am using Laravel 5.2 version
Note: I want to give time as well with date to rectify result,
On giving [example: 2017-03-08 11:15:00] shows syntax error

working query in mysql
`SELECT COUNT(orderbookings.id), SUM(orderbookings.grand_total), shops.shop_name FROM`shops`LEFT JOIN orderbookings on orderbookings.shop_id = shops.id and orderbookings.created_at BETWEEN "2015-10-22 17:02:02" AND "2017-03-07 17:02:02" GROUP BY shops.id`
But not able to to convert in eloquent

Comment: What is the syntax error you get using your query?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
$join->on('orderbookings.created_at', '>=', date("Y-m-d"));
```

You don't need to use `DB::raw`, and leaving the second parameter `null` for `date`, assumes `"now"`.

If this doesn't solve your issue, please post the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: Your answer not works for me shows error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2017-03-08' in 'on clause'`